# What's the definition of space according to this particular use?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> On the dimensionality of **odor space** ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4491593))

I found an interesting article that used the word **odor space**. To me this is very strange, because space means a three or two dimensional space, so why is it being used this way and what would be the matching definition for the word space in this particular context?

Comment: The article explains the meaning of odor 'space' quite thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

"Space" in that sense is [a mathematical concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)), used to mean a "universe", or range and organization of possible values, i.e. a set of data and its organization. A common example is [color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space), used to describe the gamut of colors displayed on a monitor.

Answer (score 0):

This definition from Collins Dictionary is appropriate:

> 11. mathematics
>       a collection of unspecified points having properties that obey a specified set of axioms

[Space](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/space)

Consider the three-dimensional space in which we all exist. Imagine a cube-shaped volume within that. It has these dimensions: width, height, and depth. Locations along these are usually denoted in mathematics by *x*, *y*, and *z* respectively. You can specify any point within that volume or 'space' by three numbers, representing distances along these three axes, thus 0,0,0 could be the bottom left front corner. The numbers could be millimetres, feet, or some arbitrary units you made up. This space is *imaginary*, an idea, an abstraction. Now consider the perception of colour by the human eye and brain. The eye has receptors for red, green, and blue. Different colours stimulate these in varying amounts, so that any particular colour seen can be given an *R*, *G*, and *B* value. Thus you could say that any arbitrarily chosen colour lies at a point in a three-dimensional colour space. The paper you link to discusses attempts to construct an abstract 'space' in which odours lie; 128 is mentioned as a possible number of dimensions.